# Writing to the console's standard output using StreamWriter

Tags: c#

Disclaimer: I come from a C++ background and started C# recently.

For some reason, I cannot write to the console's standard output like this:

```
new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput()).Write("Stackoverflow");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use StreamWriter?

Comment: @Aurril I'm making a logger class that can register/unregister streamwriters

Comment: There is a great logging framework for .net already. It's called log4net and you can add it to your project via NuGet. You might want to give it a go.

Comment: @Aurril Yea, I know, but it seems a bit too bloated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
sw.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(sw);
sw.WriteLine("Stackoverflow");
```